# jquery checking if the selected page is current page

Tags: jquery

How to check using jquery if the page selected in drop down menu is the one that i'm already on, so that it's not being loaded again?
here is a snippet:

```
$('select').change(function () {    
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use an `if` statement:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    if(window.location.href != this.value)
        window.location.href = this.value;
});
```

Comment: ok, it's still loading, but i guess that problem is in my back end part of code. do u have any idea how to make my page that i'm on "selected" so that if it's selected it's not being rendered again when i choose it on drop down menu? thanks once again

Comment: @user2099129 Adding the `selected="selected"` attribute to the correct `<option>` tag in your HTML would be the easiest option. If you can't do it before page load, however, you could do it with jQuery.

Comment: @popnoodles It gives the same result, but there are a few advantages to `this.value`. You're accessing the property directly, rather than calling functions, so it's faster, and it's also easier to type (no `$` or parentheses). This is one of those times where jQuery is total overkill, and rather than encouraging people to use what they're used to we should be encouraging them to think about whether or not a framework is necessary (in this case it's definitely not).

Comment: @user2099129 Just had a thought, if your `<select>` contains relative URLs then the values may never match. You might want to check if `window.location.href` contains that substring if that is the case: `if(window.location.href.indexOf(this.value) == -1)`